# Suppress javadoc warnings only for specific packages

Tags: java, gradle, antlr, javadoc

I'm using ANTLR which generates source code files. I'd like Javadoc to generate documentation for these generated files alongside the docs for my other code. However, it generates very many warnings because the generated code doesn't have Javadoc comments.

In Gradle's Javadoc configuration, there's the `excludes` option but that omits the docs for that code entirely. There's also the option to just suppress warnings globally but I also don't want either that since the warnings are helpful in general, just not for generated code.

I'd like to suppress Javadoc warnings only for the generated code which is in a specific folder and has a specific package.